# Bash: Stderr being sent to a file (when it shouldn't be!)

Tags: bash, macos, stderr

The following code is on macOS as part of `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`, in order to save and restore the shell state across all open windows and tabs (note that this is therefore the very old `bash 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin23)`):

```bash
  if [ -n "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE" ]; then
        echo -ne '\nSaving session...' >&2
        (umask 077; echo 'echo Restored session: "$(/bin/date -r '$(/bin/date +%s)')"' >| "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE")
        declare -F shell_session_save_user_state >/dev/null && shell_session_save_user_state
        shell_session_history_allowed && shell_session_save_history
        echo 'completed.' >&2
    fi
```

This ends up being run on shell exit by `trap shell_session_update EXIT` (the function `shell_session_update()` runs another function which in turn contains these lines.)

Over the last week, I have found a very weird problem: sometimes, `$SHELL_SESSION_FILE` contains the line

```bash
Saving session...echo Restored session: "$(/bin/date -r 1698759014 Saving session...)"
```

rather than just `Restored session: "$(/bin/date -r 1698759014)"`.

It seems that `Saving session...` is being written to this file (more than once!) rather than being sent to stderr.

The fact that this is happening more than once leads me to believe that somehow this is happening due to several of these windows running this code in their own shells, and  in some cases stderr is being incorrectly sent to this file.

The behaviour does not seem to appear when I delete all .bash* and .profile files (or make a new user), but I can bring it back even with a very simple .bashrc -- although it does not happen in every window or every tab at every startup. It seems "non-deterministic".

As I said, this only just started happening (perhaps since Sonoma -- macOS 14 -- but also perhaps due to other changes such as updating to python 3.12). I suspect that this isn't just a broader macOS bug -- I don't see evidence that anyone else is seeing this behaviour. Perhaps something to do with interaction between file descriptors? (e.g., a weird race condition? or is there some way for an *external* program to redirect the stderr that bash sees?)

Any ideas what could cause this? (Or even suggestions for how to debug it?)

***Update:*** I am seeing this even for new users, and even on zsh (which uses a similar, but not identical, file `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal`, for this. Very weird, and points to a problem fairly "deep" in my system (but also one that is unique to me, or I assume we'd be seeing many more reports of it).

(See [this Ask Different post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/465930/apple-terminal-startup-errors-session-save-restore) for the macOS-related symptoms of this problem.)

Comment: Hey, upvoters (and others): are you seeing behavior like this, or just finding it interesting?

Comment: Doing `set -o xtrace` might help understand what's going on. Here could be having to do with the trap firing several times including within itsefl like also in subshells for some reason, or maybe some of the functions being exported (beware of `set -a` / `set -o allexport`), or `$BASH_ENV` being set or some other crazy things along those lines.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The error only seems to occur when I close the shell by quitting Terminal.app (i.e., not from an explicit `exit`), which means that the trace output gets swallowed up without being displayed. But this is probably a useful data point of its own...

Comment: I suppose when closing the terminal, the shell is killed by SIGHUP or SIGTERM. Do you have handlers for those? You could try running a shell session within `script` and kill the `script` process to simulate a `Terminal.app` closure.

Comment: This really does seem to be macOS specific and is apparently related to Terminal.app. It looks like your question on [apple.se] is gaining some traction, would you agree that it makes sense to close this one and focus on the other?

Comment: We’re seeing reports of this by people [using `zsh` on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/466160/5472) as well now.